# `parser.parse()` - how to specify allowed formats (and it's order)

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-dateutil

I want to create my own date parser. I like `parser.parse()` function but if I have:

```
date1 = '2022/11/10'
date2 = '10/11/2022'

parser.parse(date1)
parser.parse(date2)
```

Then the results are:

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 10, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 11, 0, 0)
```

I want to always first try to parse the day with month between day and year. So the `parser.parse(date2)` should return November, not October. What is more I want to parse only the dates which includes days, month, and years, so parser.parse("20") should return an error and not  `datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 0, 0)`. I would simply write my own function to parse dates (couple of `if` statements) but I'm afraid that it might works very slow with big data.

Comment: You could try different formats with a `try/except` around each, until it succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) ? It looks like what you want : just call each time with a different format you want to try for the input.

```py
import datetime as dt
from typing import Optional


def my_date_parser(some_date_string: str) -> Optional[dt.date]:
    expected_date_formats = [
        # see https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior
        "%d/%m/%Y",
        "%Y/%m/%d",
        # ...
    ]
    for expected_date_format in expected_date_formats:
        try:
            return dt.datetime.strptime(some_date_string, expected_date_format).date()
        except ValueError:
            continue  # ignore this one
    else:  # if the for-loop went through, it means that nothing matches
        return None


date1 = '2022/11/10'
date2 = '10/11/2022'
print(date1, my_date_parser(date1))  # 2022/11/10 2022-11-10
print(date2, my_date_parser(date2))  # 10/11/2022 2022-11-10
```